# Is there a way to tell how many buildings have been destroyed in SC2 - The Dig?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

Been playing StarCraft 2, and I'm wondering if there is a way to tell how many buildings you have destroyed in the level "The Dig" working towards the achievement for destroying 50 buildings with the giant laser? Is there a counter somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to check exactly how many buildings you've killed with the laser, but the laser does show how many total kills it has when it's selected, so you can use that as a rough estimate. (Obviously, if you kill nothing but buildings with the laser, then the kill count tells you exactly what you need to know. But on Hard difficulty, which is what the achievement requires, that might be, well, hard.)

You're guaranteed to get the achievement if you simply kill all of the Protoss buildings on the map, or at least the vast majority of them. Some strategies are discussed on [Liquipedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Campaign/The_Dig#Achievements), including:

- Push through the bases with your units, using them to spot for the laser.
- Use floating buildings or Vikings to spot (possibly using cliffs to your advantage). In some areas, the Protoss will keep trying to rebuild the buildings you destroy, so you can just continue to pick them off and you'll eventually hit 50 that way.
- Use Orbital Commands to Scan around the map and kill the buildings you reveal that way. Orbital Commands are unlocked after 12 missions according to [this discussion](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/832195365).

Comment: Can I go on to other levels and then come back with better equipment and such and beat it later? Right now I don't have any good flying vehicles I have to spot with buildings. Or is the level locked in at what technology I have?

Comment: If you haven't beaten the level yet, you should be able to play other missions to unlock more stuff before coming back. If you've already beaten it and you're replaying it, I think you're stuck with whatever you had the first time.

Comment: Already beaten it. I'll have to check it out.

Comment: Yes, once you've beaten it, you're stuck with the stuff you've got.